# Extract new data frame from existing, based on particular values in a column in R language

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 3 observations, which are name, age, school

```
Name | Age | School 
John   25     STM | 
Anne   20     CODC | 
clark  25     GCC | 
Tim    25     BBC | 
Mary   15     CBIC
```

How to extract the names who's age in equal to 25 and 20

Comment: `df[df$Age %in% c(20, 25),]` or `df$Name[df$Age %in% c(20, 25)]` if you just want the names

Comment: You might want to look through an R tutorial. A built-in one is `RShowDoc("R-intro", type = "html")`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install the tidyverse packages and start learning how to use them from now. In dplyr notation what you need looks like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(
  Name = c("John", "Anne", "Clark", "Tim", "Mary"),
  Age = c(25, 20, 25, 25, 15),
  School = c("STM", "CODC", "GCC", "BBC", "CBIC")
)

desired_names <- df %>% 
  filter(Age %in% c(25,15) %>%
  select(Name) # use pull(Name) instead if you want the names as a vector
```